# $Ajax - getting coldfusion error " ColdFusion was unable to add the text you specified to the output stream."

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm stopped on a couple of pages because of this error.  I'm not sure why my cfc method is returning anything to the output stream. It's the success function that is returning the error message. The database is being updated correctly.

```
function onSelectChange(){
        var selected = $("#MrMrsSelect option:selected");
        if(selected.val() != 0){
            //alert("You Selected " + selected.text() + "for " + SelectedInvid);
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=FixMrMrs",
                 data: "indivNum=" + SelectedInvid + "&MrMrs=" + selected.text(),
                 error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     // show error
                     alert(errorThrown);
                     },
                 success: function(data ) {
            alert(data);
     },
```

CFC:

```
        <cffunction name="FixMrMrs" output="false" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="IndivNum" required="True" type="string" default="">
        <cfargument name="MrMrs" required="True" type="string" default="">
        <cfset var qResults = "">
        <cfquery name="qResults" datasource="#request.dsn#">
            UPDATE users_info
            SET  Mr_Mrs_Ms_Miss = '#arguments.MrMrs#'
            WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.IndivNum#" />
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn true>
        </cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't expect the method to return anything, don't return anything.

base.cfc:

```
<cffunction name="FixMrMrs" returntype="void" output="false" access="remote" returnformat="plain">
    <cfargument name="IndivNum" required="True" type="string" default="">
    <cfargument name="MrMrs" required="True" type="string" default="">
    <cfset var qResults = "">
    <cfquery name="qResults" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        UPDATE users_info
        SET  Mr_Mrs_Ms_Miss = '#arguments.MrMrs#'
        WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.IndivNum#" />
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

javascript:

```
function onSelectChange(){
    var selected = $("#MrMrsSelect option:selected");
    if(selected.val() != 0){
        //alert("You Selected " + selected.text() + "for " + SelectedInvid);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=FixMrMrs",
            data: "indivNum=" + SelectedInvid + "&MrMrs=" + selected.text(),
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // show error
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(data ) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Based on my testing using Railo (which mimics CF9 for the most part here), you should get an empty alert.

Comment: Yes, setting the datatype to html and the return type makes a big difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things...

In your Ajax call, try and specify, `&returnFormat=json`

Also, add this...

```
<cfset var qResults = "">
<cfcontent type="application/json" />
```

To your CFC return, that way the response headers will return Json.

Comment: Syntax error: Jason parse: Unexpected character.  // empty temp dupe files
     for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
         {
           var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
           alert('Empty tables for ' + nextChar);
     
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
         url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=getIndDupesV5_Start&returnFormat=json",
         data: "NextLetter=" + nextChar,
          success: function(data ) {
            alert(data);
           },
         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
          // show error 
          alert(errorThrown); 
          } 
         });
       }

Comment: <cfset var qResults = ""> was alrteady in the function

Comment: I'm not really expecting anything back from the cffunction.

Comment: Try and open up firebug in firefox and see what the CF is returning.